# ColdFusion 5 setup files

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to install ColdFusion 5 but it looks like data2.cab file is missing from my copy. I understand on Adam Cameron's Dev Blog he had a copy of Coldfusion 5 from the document he wrote about installing it on Windows 7 64bit. Does anyone have a copy of the software please?

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use CF 5? It is about 20 years old and has been updated substantially.

Comment: Please include a link to the blog as well as all the information from the blog that is needed to answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can find installers for older versions of ColdFusion on a community maintained site: http://www.cfmlrepo.com/

I doubt you'll be able to get it up and running reliably as it's a 32-bit installer and won't run on modern Windows. It's pre-Java, so you'll also have issues with C compatibility for things like custom CFX tags. If you've got an old OS on a server somewhere, maybe you can do something with it.

What problem are you trying to address? Working on a legacy application? CF 5 should no longer be running any kind of production sites as there are a world of security issues given the modern Internet.

If possible, I'd suggest trying to run the code on the open source Lucee CFML engine https://www.lucee.org/. Depending on the complexity of your application, it won't just be a matter of setting up data sources and running the code. But in the long run, if this app needs to exist for a while more, it'll be a safer and less expensive solution.

If you have more questions about CF 5, you'll probably find more help on the CFML Slack channel. You can get an invite here: https://cfml-slack.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Thank you. It is needed to be able to migrate a system to a newer platform then to decommission it. Many thanks

Comment: @AdamWinspeare If it's a CF5 application, it probably would be a lot better to try to rewrite the application. Modern CF is, quite literally, a different animal. Almost everything that would have been done in CF5 is done a lot better in modern CF or Lucee. Personally, I'd migrate the application, but immediately look at what needs to happen to rewrite it in modern CF.

Comment: Also should mention that simply putting the server on more modern hardware that is well beyond the limitations of CF5 will also change how this application operates.